# Uploading Files through Selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I've been trying to upload files through selenium using python. I've been following a guide that says to use:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("IdOfInputTypeFile").send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/image.png")
```

from this site: http://allselenium.info/file-upload-using-python-selenium-webdriver/

However, this only works after manually clicking upload, getting the opload file pop up window and then closing it. If I run the command before hand, it doesn't do anything.

However, I can't close the popup window in selenium. So this isn't a viable method for automation.

Comment: [This](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5310/how-to-close-pop-up-window-in-selenium-webdriver) could help in closing the pop-up window.

Comment: I think that's in java. Also the popup window is the window that pops up when you're asked to specify what file you want to upload. The popup window in that question is still an element of the page.

Comment: Can you provide the (minimal amount of) HTML and webdriver code to reproduce the behavior?  Or provide a test site?

Answer (score 0):

if you are uploading a file in java or python that will open the window popup menu at that time it is safe to use Autoit always weather it is java or python. AutoIT is the best option to upload the File.

You only need to install AutoIt https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoIt/0.3 or just "pip install -U pyautoit" through the cmd screen

type "import autoit" on your script page

Type the following before the file dialog pops up in your script:

1. autoit.win_active("Open")
2. autoit.control_send("Open","Edit1",r"C:\Users\uu\Desktop\Filename.txt")
3. autoit.control_send("Open","Edit1","{ENTER}")

**instead of control_send you can use,**

```
autoit.control_set_text("Open","Edit1",r"C:\Users\uu\Desktop\Filename.txt")
```

4. compile it to get an .exe file(Filename.exe)
5. Now from python call the .exe file like

**Import this in your code,**

```
import os
import os.system('C:\images\Filename.exe') #path of the .exe file
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: AutoIT is clearly not the best option to upload a file.  It's dependent upon Windows and OS level dialogue names (which can vary).